# Generalizing 1D function to higher dimensions

Tags: functions, special-functions, hyperbolic-functions

I have a function in 1D given by $f(x) = \tanh(x-x_1) + \tanh(x-x_2)$. I want to generalize this to two dimensions, such that it describes a circle. The function $f(x,y)$ has to have a form such that it will reduce to $f(x)$ for $y\rightarrow 0$.

How can I create such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by that it should describe a circle, can you elaborate that?

If you want a rotational symmetry you can use use the radius $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ as an argument:

$F(x,y) := f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ but in this of course only uses the part of $f$ with a positive argument, that means that $f(x,0) = f(|x|)$.

EDIT: $f(x) = \tanh(x-x_1)-\tanh(x+x_1)$, this means that the function is symmetrical $f(x) = f(-x)$ and you can just use the idea above:

Define: $$F(x,y) = f(r) = f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)= \tanh(x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x_1)-\tanh(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x_1)$$

Therefore

$$F(x,0) = f(|x|) = f(x)$$

since $f(-x) = \tanh(-x-x_1)-\tanh(-x+x_1) = -\tanh(x+x_1)+\tanh(x-x_1) = f(x)$.

Comment: $f(x)$ describes a "well". In 2D, I want a function that describes the circle that comes when this well is rotated around the point $(x,y)=0$

Comment: Ah, but then you mean $f(x) = \color{red}{-} \tanh(x-x_1)+\tanh(x-x_2) = \tanh(\color{red}{x_1-x})+\tanh(x-x_2)$ , do you?

Comment: I believe the $f(x)$ I wrote in the OP is correct, that creates a well

Comment: Compare those two plots [version of OP](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+tanh%28x%E2%88%922%29%2Btanh%28x%E2%88%923%29), [suggested version](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+tanh%282-x%29%2Btanh%28x%E2%88%923%29), so I think only the second one creates a well (by well I mean a that the curve goes down to a minimum and up again to the same level as before?).

Comment: I apologize, the $f(x)$ I should have given you in the OP is $f(x) = \tanh(x-x_1)-\tanh(x+x_1)$ for some $x_1$. This creates a well.

Comment: No problem, I updated my answer, you can use the original idea. I hope this asnwers your question!